# need help in zip conversion using Gstream

Tags: c#, gzip, gzipstream

i am using this code for compression of file to zip

```
     public static void Compress(FileInfo fileToCompress)
    {
        using (FileStream originalFileStream = fileToCompress.OpenRead())
        {
            if ((File.GetAttributes(fileToCompress.FullName) & FileAttributes.Hidden) != FileAttributes.Hidden & fileToCompress.Extension != ".zip")
            {
                using (FileStream compressedFileStream = File.Create(fileToCompress.FullName + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd_MM_yyyy") + ".zip"))
                {

                    using (GZipStream compressionStream = new GZipStream(compressedFileStream, CompressionMode.Compress))
                    {
                        originalFileStream.CopyTo(compressedFileStream);
                        Console.WriteLine("Compressed {0} from {1} to {2} bytes.",
                            fileToCompress.Name, fileToCompress.Length.ToString(), compressedFileStream.Length.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

with this code i convert file to zip
for example i have file with name myfile.pdf
what it does, it saves this file with myfile.pdf_31_7_2013.zip
but the problem is when i extract this zip it contains my file with extention
myfile.pdf_31_7_2013 which will be invaild file coz its extention changed from .pdf to .pdf_31_7_2013

so its extention is changed. i want to modify code in a way that zip name should be the same
as it performs right now. but inside that my file should be with only myfile.pdf

please help me to solve this. thanks in advance

Comment: First problem: a GZipStream isn't a zip file, so shouldn't be called a zip file. As for the rest - it's your naming scheme... you should adjust it to whatever you want. For example, you could put the date *before* the extension instead of after it...

Comment: @Jon: make this an answer... mer is creating a gzip file and - by default - gzip extraction automagically removes the extension (correctly ".gz"), leaving the described filename.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change the file format so that:

- The extension is `gz`
- The part *before* the extension is appropriate for your file, so that when `.gz` has been removed, it will be a reasonable filename.

So instead of converting `myfile.pdf` into `myfile.pdf_31_7_2013.zip`, I'd convert it into `myfile-20130731.pdf.gz`. When it's extract, it will become `myfile-20130731.pdf`. Note that using `yyyyMMdd` is cleaner than `MM_d_yyyy` as it's sortable and unambiguous.